# String manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I gave a poor description in my prev. question on what i want to do,

so here's another shot:

i have this string:

```
"<HTML>\n"+
"<P><BODY>\n"+
"<%for(var i=0;i<5;i++){%>\n"+
"<%response.body+=i;%><br/><br/>\n"+
"<%}%>\n"+
"<table border=’1’ width=”100%”>\n"+
"</BODY></P>\n"+
"</HTML>\n";
```

and i want to manipulate this into the following:

```
"response.body+=<HTML>;\n"+
"response.body+=<P><BODY>;\n"+
"for(var i=0;i<5;i++){\n"+
"response.body+=i;response.body+=<br/><br/>;\n"+
"response.body+=</BODY></P>;\n"+
"response.body+=</HTML>;\n";
```

meaning; adding to anything not in "<% some code %>"

this: "response.body+=" and ";".

how can it be done?

Comment: What happened to your other question? I took the trouble to answer it and now it's gone. Also, is it deliberate that the `<% ... %>` tags are missing from your desired result? And speaking of `<% ... %>` - such tags imply JSP or ASP server-side code, so why do you have that in a JavaScript string?

Comment: Care to tell us what is the reason for that?

Comment: @nnnnnn it was voted down 5 times, had to delete it.
yes it is deliberate, and its JST. its for doing some stuff in node.js

Comment: You don't have to delete things just because they get downvoted. You could've edited the other question. Also, why is the `<table>` element and the closing `}` from the `for` missing from the desired output?

Comment: @nnnnnn thank you for your answer, but its was badly written,so im sorry for the deletion

Comment: @Itzik984 Having a question down voted doesn't necessarily mean it not worth being asked.  By deleting it, you're trashing others' effort who tried to help.

Comment: @shinkou i know. but i wanted it to be well phrased, because i need an answer. i thanked nnnnnn for his answer on the previous question and again for this.

Comment: every bone in my body says there's an easier way of achieving what you want. Mind giving some context?

Comment: @Itzik984 Then why do you think we need the *edit* function?

Comment: @shinkou let it go. i said im sorry to nnnnnn.

Comment: @PabloFernandez the first string is the string given to me in the JST file, i have to parse it in order to get the needed html and js lines, so i need to manipulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My motivation to provide a complete answer is low given that I already answered your other question and now it's been deleted, but you could try something like the following:

```
yourString.replace(/'/g,"\\'")
          .replace(/(<[^%>]+>)/g,"response.body+='$1';")
          .replace(/<%|%>/g,"");
```

I'm assuming you intended to have the html tags in single quotes as in your other question.